# How do I build a 2D json object with python dictionaries?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm scraping the web and pulling html attributes out as a dictionary and want to compile all of these as ojbects into a json file.

The dictionary looks like this:

```
{'car':'ford',
   'mpg':45,
   'VIN':'A31GAFD'}
```

and I want my json file to look like (or however would be most appropriate):

```
{
    {'car':'ford',
   'mpg':45,
   'VIN':'A31GAFD'},

    {'car':'bmw',
   'mpg':12,
   'VIN':'B441GAFD'}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you want, is for the outer object to be an array instead:

```
[
    {
        'car':'ford',
        'mpg':45,
        'VIN':'A31GAFD'
    },

    {
        'car':'bmw',
        'mpg':12,
        'VIN':'B441GAFD'
    }
]
```

That is `[ ... ]` instead of `{ ... }`

If that's not what you're asking for, then please clarify your question.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I needed, I dont know why I tried making more difficult. thank you :)